# How to include table of contents into a table of contents with numbering

Tags: table-of-contents

With the package

```
\usepackage{tocbibind}
```

I can include the table of Contents in itself, however this is without numbering.
I would like to know if it's possible to include a number in the contents (so it would be like a section) and then include this in the table of contents.

an example would be like,

1. Abstract
2. Contents
3. Section 1

and then in the table of contents it would show all these 3.

Comment: I think perhaps the answer would depend on the documentclass you're using, can you add that info to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a standard class you can use package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[\jobname]{toc}
\renewcommand*\tableofcontents{\listoftoc[{\contentsname}]{toc}}
\setuptoc{toc}{numbered}

\begin{document}
\section{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Package `tocbasic` is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. The KOMA-Script classes load it automatically:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\setuptoc{toc}{numbered}

\begin{document}
\section{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]